# Present perfect or past simple when it is used with time adverb

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

I'm not a native speaker so to understand the difference between past simple and present perfect is giving me a headache sometimes. I have learned, that when it is used in a sentence a time adverb describing a past event, I need to use present simple. But a few days ago I heard on the TV the following sentence:

> It is better than what you have done previously.

But I would use:

> It is better than what you did previously.

Because `previously, yesterday, last week`  - all of these adverbs are set the story into the past. At least to me. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small difference between using the simple present and present perfect in cases like those. The difference is that simple present may have more specificity than present perfect.

> It is better than what you did previously.

This might seem to imply that "what you did" comprised a single event.

> It is better than what you have done previously.

This can open the scope a little, and may refer to multiple events.

Note that the distinction here is small, and in actual usage either could be used to suggest a single event or multiple events.

Also be aware that a more specific time adverb (*yesterday*, *last Monday*) likewise narrows the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Present Simple is used when something is set at a *specific point* in the past.

Present Perfect is about something that happened in the past—no matter when exactly—and is a fact now because of that.

E. g., **I have read this book** means that I have this experience of reading this book, it is **now** part of my intellectual "luggage". But whether I read it last week or 10 years ago is not essential.

Since "previously" is not about a specific time, this is why Present Perfect is used.

Answer (score 1):

The time expression in a present perfect construction must not exclude the present. With **previously** there is an implicit reference to the present: what has happened *previously* happened *before now*.